# Pascal triangle produced for a particular integer K

Tags: java, algorithm, interview-questions

Please be brutal and let me know what you think of the code below, if written at an interview.

Problem:

> Given an index *k*, return the kth row of the Pascal's triangle.
>
> For example, given k = 3, return [1,3,3,1].
>
> **Time it took:**
>   25 minutes (perfectly working solution)
>
> **Space Complexity:**
>   O(K)
>
> **Time Complexity:**
>   O(N<sup>2</sup>)?

---

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getRow(int rowIndex) {
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> allList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> toAdd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(rowIndex==0){
        toAdd.add(1);
        return toAdd;
    }

    if(rowIndex>=1){
        toAdd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        toAdd.add(1);
        toAdd.add(1);
        allList.add(toAdd);
        if(rowIndex==1){
            return toAdd;
        }
    }
    for(int i=1; i<rowIndex; i++){
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        temp.add(1);
        for(int j=1; j<allList.get(i-1).size(); j++){
            temp.add(allList.get(i-1).get(j-1) + allList.get(i-1).get(j));
        }
        temp.add(1);
        allList.add(temp);
    }
    return allList.get(rowIndex-1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Types

Given the description, I would assume that the return value is supposed to be `int[]` instead of `List<Integer>`....

... but, you are not using the more general `List<Integer>` value, but instead the `ArrayList<Integer>`. Always use the most general class type for your interfaces.

Also, by keeping the data as Integer values, you are doing a lot of boxing, and unboxing in the loops. Really, you should keep the calculations as Java primitives (`int`), and then box the results if needed.

### Conditions

Your code has a special-case for row 0, where it returns `[1]`. By preference, I recommend not having special cases, although it is a rule I bend often.

Still, after the `rowIndex == 0` special case, you then check to see whether it is `rowIndex >= 1`. This does not make sense because the `rowIndex == 0` case returned from the function, so the other condition is useless. Well, not quite useless, it avoids an error condition for negative values. But, the negative-value condition should have been checked at the method start. Basically, it is a useless check. Consider this restructure:

```
if (rowIndex < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nevative row");
}
if(rowIndex==0){
    toAdd.add(1);
    return toAdd;
}

toAdd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
toAdd.add(1);
toAdd.add(1);
allList.add(toAdd);
if(rowIndex==1){
    return toAdd;
}
```

### Conclusion

I agree that the complexity is about *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, but I know it must be psosible to do it faster. The data types are a problem, but the result looks accurate.

### Alternative...

So, I cheated, and looked at wiki, and it has a [relatively easy function for calculating the row values for a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself). I adapted it here. This is the way I would have done it, if I was able to google the algorithm. I would have used a similar approach to you, but as arrays-of-int instead, if I could not search the algorithm.

```
public static final int[] pascalRow(final int row) {
    // using same names as wikipedia:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Calculating_a_row_or_diagonal_by_itself
    int n = row + 1;
    int[] ret = new int[n];
    int val = 1;
    final int mid = (n)/2;
    for (int k = 0; k <= mid; k++) {
        ret[k] = val;
        ret[n - 1 - k] = val;
        val = (int)(val * ((n - k - 1) / (double)(k + 1)));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the under condition is useless. If rowIndex is 0, then my function returns end of story. As far as the [x, x,x]values going, that's just how the problem describes it, the return value is supposed to be a List; so that's not an issue. Thank you for your time as always.

Comment: @bazang - edited to include an 'revised' version of what I expect.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an alternative design:**

Write a function that takes a row and returns the next row, and then call this function `k` times:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getNextRow(ArrayList<Integer> currRow)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> nextRow = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    nextRow.add(1);
    for (int i=0; i<currRow.size()-1; i++)
        nextRow.add(currRow.get(i)+currRow.get(i+1));
    nextRow.add(1);
    return nextRow;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getRow(int rowIndex)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    row.add(1);
    for (int i=0; i<rowIndex; i++)
        row = getNextRow(row);
    return row;
}
```